# Grub not loading after Windows 8 Install

Tags: grub2, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

My system was configured to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and Windows 7. Today I got my hands on the MSDN release of Windows 8 and I installed it over my Windows 7. Now the computer just boots to Windows 8 directly without loading the GRUB screen.

So I followed the steps as suggested in: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows. Running this command:

```
    ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
```

gives the following output:

```
    total 0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 11 07:51 Entertainment -> ../../sda2
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 11 02:45 PENDRIVE -> ../../sdb1
```

Also `fdisk -l` command gives this as the output:

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x1246aa23

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1   *        2048   319582199   159790076    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda2       319582208   602906623   141662208    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda3       602908672   625135615    11113472   83  Linux

    Disk /dev/sdb: 1939 MB, 1939865600 bytes
    64 heads, 63 sectors/track, 939 cylinders, total 3788800 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdb1   *        2248     3788799     1893276    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

So I assume that I have to run this: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda3` to get GRUB up and running. But I am getting this error:

```
    /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot/grub (is /dev mounted?).
```

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction? The current Ubuntu installation is far too customized to my needs to lose it to a boot manager issue! Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The GRUB needs to reside in front of all partitions on the device, therefore you should run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

whereas using **/dev/sda3** would install it only to the third partition. See the guide *Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows* you referred to:

> From here, **find only the drive name, ignore the partition number**, that is, for partitions labeled "root", "data2", "fat", "home" and "swap" it's all still **just sda**. This is due to the fact that GRUB is installed in the MBR of the drive, and not on a partition.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

instead. It will find your /boot/ folder on any of the partitions.

If this does not work, you can try the following (assuming you do not have a separate boot partition, as it should show from your commands):

Boot into the live cd and open a terminal.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
```

This will mount your ubuntu install to /mnt

Then run this command

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-directory=/mnt/boot/
```

This will tell grub that it should install grub to sda, and that it should not look for /boot/, as this is located on sda3.

Comment: When I try to mount the drive it says I have to specify the filesystem type. Any suggestions?